# Not able to import "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager" to Angular NativeScript project

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am using [nativescript-IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-IQKeyboardManager) plugin in my NativeScript Angular app. I want to access the `IQKeyboardManger` object so that I can acess full `IQKeyboardManager` APIs to tweak appearance and behavior.

Bu the issue is, I am not able to import or use the IQKeyboardManager object in my project.

I have followed their documentation by adding a `references.d.ts` file. And also installing `npm install --save-dev tns-platform-declarations`

Next, when I try to initialize an instance of IQKeybardManger with the following code. It does not let me initialize.

```
const iqKeyboard = IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager();
```

I have also tried importing `IQKeyboardManger` by directly importing in my module file using following line of code.

```
import {IQKeyboardManager} from "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager";
```

This import gives the following error.

```
nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Next, I have also tried by registering the element mentioned in their documentation. Which does not work as well. [documentation](https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-IQKeyboardManager#readme)

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular";
registerElement("TextViewWithHint", () => require("nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager").TextViewWithHint);
```

Any kind help would be appreciated. Please let me know how to get this to work and what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!